# How to install the latest Emacs in 12.04?

Tags: 12.04, compiling, emacs

In 12.04 , emacs version is 23.3.1.
How to install the latest version ?

I remember there is a PPA about the newer Emacs.

Emacs 24.5 can be compiled and installed manually in 12.04?

Is here anyone who compiles Emacs 24.5 in Ubuntu 12.04?

Which one should I use `sudo apt-get build-dep emacs23` or `sudo apt-get build-dep emacs24`, if I compile Emacs 24.5 in 12.04?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The package `emacs24` isn't available on Precise, the command

```
sudo apt-get build-dep emacs24
```

wouldn't help.

---

To compile the current (2015-11-25) stable release

```
sudo apt-get install checkinstall
mkdir -p ~/src
cd ~/src
wget http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/emacs/emacs-24.5.tar.gz
tar xf emacs-24.5.tar.gz
cd emacs-24.5
./configure
make
sudo checkinstall
```

---

Or you could use the PPA `ppa:ubuntu-elisp/ppa` to install the bleeding edge version.

I quote ([from here](https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-elisp/+archive/ubuntu/ppa)):

> The Official ;-) Ubuntu Emacs Daily Snapshot PPA.

---

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:ubuntu-elisp/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install emacs-snapshot
```

The commands above will install an *additional* version of emacs in your system.

[image]

Comment: thx, I need a stable.

Comment: I found these dependencies useful: `sudo apt-get install build-essential texinfo libx11-dev libxpm-dev libjpeg-dev libpng-dev libgif-dev libtiff-dev libgtk2.0-dev libncurses-dev `